# how to choose a selection in a dropdown menu without the cursor being on it

Tags: interface, select, quick-favorites

You can scroll through any dropdown menu with the mousewheel, but how do you actually choose your selection?

I started to use HOps lately and you can't replace the quick favourites shortcut for both object and edit mode: You can still access the quick favs fast by tapping q twice and even select your wanted function with the mousewheel but...how to choose it then? Not every function in there has a dedicated shortcut but if you can select things with the mousewheel then you can surely choose them somehow aswell without using the mouse cursor...right?

[image]

Comment: Press Enter or Return?

Comment: It's Enter, yes!

For some reason enter didn't work when I tried it last time, oh well. Thanks for the answer!